# Combining linked lists iteratively

Tags: python, linked-list, iteration

I'm trying to combine two linked lists iteratively, but what I have right now is giving me the reverse of the result. Is there a way to combine the lists in the correct order without having to reverse if after the result list is created?

```
class Link: 
    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __add__(self, lst):
        """ 
        >>>s = Link(1, Link(2))
        >>>s + Link(3,Link(4))
        Link(1,Link(2,Link(3,Link(4))))
        """
        result = Link.empty 
        while self is not Link.empty: 
            result = Link(self.first,result)
            self = self.rest 

        while lst is not Link.empty: 
            result = Link(lst.first, result)
            lst = lst.rest 
        return result
```

Comment: Looks like you've created a stack. :)

Comment: Are your lists intended to be immutable? It matters because immutable lists allow you to take some shortcuts (e.g. reusing part of a list) that you can't do if the list might be modified by other code).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid changing `self`, find the end of the first list, and add the second list to it.

```
def __add__(self, lst):
    current = self

    while current.rest != self.empty:
        current = current.rest

    current.rest = lst

    return self
```

Or, if you prefer to return a new linked list:

```
def __add__(self, lst):
    new_list = Link(self.first)
    new_link = new_list

    current = self

    while current.rest != self.empty:
        new_link.rest = Link(current.first)
        new_link = new_link.rest

        current = current.rest

    current = lst

    while current != self.empty:
        new_link.rest = Link(current.first)
        new_link = new_link.rest

        current = current.rest

    return new_list
```

Note: this will make references to each `Link.first` value (not independent copies).

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, to combine two linked lists, all you need to do is find the **tail** of the first list, and connect it with the **head** of the second list, and then return the head of the first list. The major problem with the current code is that you do not keep around the head of the first list.

I'm assuming that you want the `__add__` method to create a copy made up of `self` followed by `lst`, so simply create copies of the `Link`s from `self` first and then `lst` and attach them as you iterate. Like so:

```
def __add__(self, lst):
    result = Link(self.first)
    cur = result
    self = self.rest
    # Copy our list
    while self is not Link.empty:
        cur.rest = Link(self.first)
        cur = cur.rest
        self = self.rest
    # Copy and connect the Links in lst
    while lst is not Link.empty:
        cur.rest = Link(lst.first)
        cur = cur.rest
        lst = lst.rest
    return result
```

To diagnose what's wrong with the current code, consider stepping through with an example. Assume `self` is `Link(1,Link(2))`.

```
    result = Link.empty 
    while self is not Link.empty: 
        result = Link(self.first,result)
```

What's `result` now?

- `Link(self.first,result)`
- is `Link(1, Link.empty)`

  ```
      self = self.rest
  ```

Now `self` is `Link(2,())`

```
        result = Link(self.first,result)
```

What's `result` now?

- `Link(self.first,result)`
- is `Link(2, Link(1, Link.empty))`

Oops. Found the problem; you are connecting the links in reverse.